# converting html to pdf using c# and asp.net with itextsharp

Tags: .net

I am using one static table which is in a panel conrol
how to convert html content inside the panel to pdf
please help me to convert to pdf as soon as button export is clicked

Aspx code:-

```
<table width="100%">  
   <tr>
      <td>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlPerson" runat="server">
            <table border="1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; width: 200px">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #18B5F0; height: 18px; color: White; border: 1px solid white">
                        <b>Personal Details</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Age:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>City:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Country:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export"  />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

C#.net Code:-

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Populate DataTable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    dt.Columns.Add("City");
    dt.Columns.Add("Country");
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[0]["Name"] = "Mudassar Khan";
    dt.Rows[0]["Age"] = "27";
    dt.Rows[0]["City"] = "Mumbai";
    dt.Rows[0]["Country"] = "India";

    //Bind Datatable to Labels
    lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    lblAge.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Age"].ToString();
    lblCity.Text = dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
    lblCountry.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString();
}

protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Please do send me the C# Code for this Export button

Comment: There are many example available online. You should come up with some idea and seek help if that does not work.

Comment: Please help me with this example.I have seen many examples but not found. please do the need -Tariqulazam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what I did and it is creating the pdf as required

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var output = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\PersonDetail.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        document.Open();


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);
        var html = sb.ToString();
        var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), null);

        // Enumerate the elements, adding each one to the Document...
        foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
            document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);

        document.Close();

    }
```

Please read this nice article by Scott Mitchell at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx and decide what is best for you. As suggested by the author in this article, parsing the HTML and adding it into the PDF has limited support and may not work for complex HTML structures.

Let me know if it helps.